# select dependiente de un input text

Tags: mysql, laravel, select

Buen dia para todos,

estoy intentando realizar un select dependiente de un input tipo text.

el input lo tengo bloqueado ya que es un dato que me trae por BD, allí me trae la ciudad, y dependiendo de la ciudad, me deberia traer los proveedores correspondiente solo a esa ciudad.
el caso es que me trae todos los proveedores, pero solo me muestra los correspondientes a esa ciudad, es decir, mi lista desplegable tiene 4 opciones de las cuales me muestra 2 y el resto me los muestra en blanco, el cual no debería permitir mostrarmelos.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En mi vista.

```
    <div class="modal-body">
       <label class="control-label">Ciudad</label>
      <input name="ciudad" id="ciudad" type="text" class="form-control" readonly="true" value="{!! $ordenG->ciudad_orden->nombre !!}">
  <label class="control-label">Proveedor</label>
  <select name="proveedor" id="proveedor" type="text" class="form-control">                            
    @foreach($proveedores as $proveedor)
    <option value="{{$proveedor->id}}">
      @if($proveedor->id_ciudad==$ordenG->id_ciudad)  
      {{$proveedor->nombre}}
      @endif
    </option>
    @endforeach
      </select>
      <label class="control-label">Observación</label>
      <textarea name= "observacion" class="form-control" rows="5" onkeyup="javascript:this.value=this.value.toUpperCase();"></textarea>

        </div>
```

En mi controlador

```
public function index(Request $request)
{
    $this->ordenRepository->pushCriteria(new RequestCriteria($request));
    $ordenes = $this->ordenRepository->all();
    $ordenCliente = Orden::where('cliente_id', Auth::user()->cliente_id)->get();
    $estadoCliente = Cliente::where('id',Auth::user()->cliente_id)->first();
    $proveedores = Proveedor::where('estado',0)->get();
    return view('ordenes.index', compact('ordenCliente','ordenes', 'proveedores'));
 }
```

Agradezco inmensamente su ayuda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intenta sacar el if de donde lo tienes un nivel hacia arriba de manera tal que solo se cree el elemento `<option>` cuando tu condición sea true, lo que traera como resultado eliminar el comportamiento de elementos vacios que antes tenias, aki esta el codigo:

```
@foreach($proveedores as $proveedor)
    @if($proveedor->id_ciudad==$ordenG->id_ciudad)
        <option value="{{$proveedor->id}}">     
            {{$proveedor->nombre}}    
        </option>
    @endif
@endforeach
```

Comment: Muchas gracias @Dariel Ramos Díaz de Villegas, era Justo lo que estaba buscando.

Comment: jajaja de nada men :)